# Flutter How to add child background image

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

I want to display this screen like FullScreen Background Image->4 Card/Container/Listview.count with child background image->Button with text. How I can do that? Background Image>Widget(Card, Container etc)>background image covered with child widget>text. I am using it as a dashboard of my app. I read a lot of questions and answers about the full-screen background but child background I couldn't find.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:onlycentertainment/constants/constants.dart';

class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  final _scaffold = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String username;

  submit() {
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Welcome $username'));
      _scaffold.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
        Navigator.pop(context, username);
      });
      //Page pop to next including saved data

    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              BackgroundWidget(size: size),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'HELLO, USER',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 30),
                          child: Text(
                            'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            maxLines: 5,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .6,
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .3,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
                                  child: Card(child: Text('1')),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .3,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
                                  child: Card(child: Text('1')),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                        image: AssetImage("assets/images/asset5.png"),
                                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  height:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .3,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                      child: Text('This is my text',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),),),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .3,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
                                  child: Card(child: Text('1')),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you drop a picture of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Now it works!

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:onlycentertainment/constants/constants.dart';

class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  final _scaffold = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String username;

  submit() {
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Welcome $username'));
      _scaffold.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
        Navigator.pop(context, username);
      });
      //Page pop to next including saved data

    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              BackgroundWidget(size: size),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          'HELLO, USER',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 30),
                          child: Text(
                            'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            maxLines: 5,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .6,
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                        image: AssetImage("assets/images/asset5.png"),
                                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  height:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .3,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                    child: Text('This is my text',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),),),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width:10),
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                        image: AssetImage("assets/images/asset5.png"),
                                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  height:
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .3,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                    child: Text('This is my text',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),),),
                                ),

                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                        image: AssetImage("assets/images/asset5.png"),
                                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  height:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .3,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                      child: Text('This is my text',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),),),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width:10),
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                        image: AssetImage("assets/images/asset5.png"),
                                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  height:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .3,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                      child: Text('This is my text',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),),),
                                ),

                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```